# Moodle Manula Enrolment up down edit

Tags: moodle

Manual Enrolment provides a feature to move up/down the methods and also edit existing enrolment. It was working for me but suddenly it did not work.
What could be the problem[image]

What could have gone wrong. Some Plugin Conflict or setting change

Answer (score 0):

The only clue I have is that your account may be missing a capability. This enrolment management page checks the user capability to perform such actions like moving down or up methods : `has_capability('moodle/course:enrolconfig', $context);`.

Can you check if your role has the capability `course:enrolconfig` ?

**Edit :**

For further capability checking, you can try to check if Moodle is able to print the actions buttons inside the code of the page (moodle/enrol/instances.php) adding under line 227, right here : https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/enrol/instances.php#L227

```
var_dump($canconfig, $instance->id);
```

This is where Moodle checks capabilities and builds the outputs for those actions.

It must print `true` for all of the methods. For futher investigation, add `var_dump($table->data);` at line 271. It should print the icons arrows for up and down moving.

Comment: Configure enrol instances in courses
moodle/course:enrolconfig     Yes
Review course enrolments
moodle/course:enrolreview     Yes
Yes

Comment: Yes the capability existed for admin and other users with admin role. It was working fine for last 3 days. I installed some plugin and after some issue have happened. I thought it was Arlo for Moodle . I have removed, run cron job. Still the problem persist...

Comment: Have you full access to the Moodle source code ? If so, you can verify that the capabilities are up through the code of the page. Maybe you can try what I added in my post for further investigations. If you do so, don't forget to remove the var_dump() functions after checking.

Comment: if ($canconfig) {
        var_dump($canconfig, $instance->id);   (new line added after 227 - gave error)
        if ($updowncount > 1) {
            $aurl = new moodle_url($url, array('action'=>'up', 'instance'=>$instance->id));

Also addiing at 271
$table->data[] = array($displayname, $users, implode('', $updown), implode('', $edit));
}
var_dump($table->data);
---------------
code did not execute and gave me error. I am stuck up  with moodle as this important feature... Can you help. I copy full code of new file. still it did not work..
Thanks for ur effort. can you help me more ..

Comment: I am also not able unenrol cohort groups also. unerolling multiple users is also giving problem..

Comment: You could try to reset your Moodle role to the initial role : go to Administration > users > permissions > define roles - then click on the role you have and use the "reset" button. Maybe this Arlo for Moodle plugin messed up with your capabilities.
You can also purge cache in Administration > development and activate debug errors display.

Comment: Have you full access to the Moodle source code ? If so, you can verify that the capabilities are up through the code of the page. --- I have full access. I am admin of the site. I have checked the capability of enrol - Yes for admin.

Comment: Tried everything. is there any way i replace few files / code... do not want reinstall everything... even for new courses it is now working.. no up/down arrows, no way hide or unenrol the cohort group...

Comment: Looking at Arlo source code, it adds new capabilities based on the plugin actions. I believe your roles may need to be reset if you uninstalled Arlo. Have you tried it for your manager role ?

Comment: No Luck. After Uninstalling Arlo. Doing all that what was told. Create a user with Manager role and even with admin, not able to up/down & edit options. I don't mind deleting all users and creating them again, but don't want to take trouble of installing so many plugins.. is there a way by replacing some files of updating database... -- Thanks for prompt reply..  this issue should be highlighted in arlo plugin...